# Сделать из нескольких коммитов один

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Какой командой можно объединить несколько коммитов в один в Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **[git rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages)**
- Объединение производится с помощью установки [`s(squash)`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits) для соответствующего чейнджсета.